# Using Context API in typescript for user login

Tags: reactjs, typescript, authentication

I have created a reducer for my context and the code looks like this

"""

```
export const AuthReducer = (state: any, action: { type: any; payload: any; }) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "LOGIN": {
            return {
                _currentUser: action.payload,
                get currentUser() {
                    return this._currentUser;
                },
                set currentUser(value) {
                    this._currentUser = value;
                },
            };
        }
             case "LOGOUT": {
            return {
                currentUser: null,
            };
        }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

"""

And I have also created my context like this
"""

```
import { createContext, useReducer } from "react";
import {AuthReducer} from "./AuthReducer";
import React, { ReactNode } from "react";

interface State {
  currentUser: any; 
}

interface AuthContextType {
  currentUser: State["currentUser"];
  dispatch: React.Dispatch<any>; 
}

interface AuthContextProviderProps {
  children: ReactNode;
}

const INITIAL_STATE: State = {
  currentUser: null,
}

export const AuthContext = createContext<AuthContextType>({
  currentUser: INITIAL_STATE.currentUser,
  dispatch: () => {}, 
});

export const AuthContextProvider: React.FC<AuthContextProviderProps> = ({
  children
}) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(AuthReducer, INITIAL_STATE);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ currentUser: state.currentUser, dispatch }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

"""

but the AuthContextProvider keeps throwing an error and I cant seem to figure out why, Can anyone help me point out where I made the mistake

Comment: what error do you get ?

Comment: I keep getting this error "const AuthContextProvider: React.FC<AuthContextProviderProps>
Type '({ children }: AuthContextProviderProps) => {}' is not assignable to type 'FC<AuthContextProviderProps>'.
  Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactElement<any, any>': type, props, key" and this error "Cannot find namespace 'AuthContext'"

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is the file extension - looks like you are using typescript so ensure the file extension on AuthContext is .tsx (otherwise .jsx for javascript)

This is because you have specified a context provider with JSX elements/syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the help.. it seems I just needed to change the file extension.. It works now